# create hash table with linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

i tried to create hash table with linked list in c ,
first the struct code is :
and i define size :
and the hash function
finally the code of insert is :
and then create an array of struct
and here is the main :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct citizens * data ;
struct citizens
{
    int id, age  ;
    char *name ;
    char gender ;
    data next ;

};

#define hash_size 50

data hash_table [hash_size] ;

int hash_function(int key)
{
    return key % hash_size ;
}

void insert_to_hash (int key_id, char *name, int age, char gender)
{
    data item = (data)malloc(sizeof(struct citizens)) ;
    data postion ;
    item->id = key_id ;
    item->age = age ;
    item->name = name ;
    item -> gender = gender ;
    item ->next = NULL ;
    int index = hash_function(key_id) ;
    postion = hash_table [index] ;
    if (item != NULL )
    {


        if (hash_table [index] ->next == NULL )
        {
            hash_table [index]->next = item ;
            item ->next = NULL ;

        }

        else
        {

            while (postion ->next != NULL )
                postion = postion->next ;

            postion ->next = item ;
            item ->next = NULL ;
        }


    }

    else
        printf("out of memory") ;

}

int main()
{

    insert_to_hash(2, "ahmad" , 20, 'M') ;


    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code , i did not get any error or warning , the compiler get stuck like this : 
[image]

Comment: I think it has sth to this `while (postion ->next != NULL )`  you checked in debuger is it stuck in there?

Comment: Tip: always prefer unsigned types when hashing. Tip2: pointers-to-pointers could simplify your program.

Comment: Have you tried changing the first if statement into a while()?

Comment: My bad, didn't see @MerMonkey's comment

Comment: @MerMonkey What does "sth" mean?

Comment: i think that the problem because of reservation in memory

Comment: the problem starts in ```  if (hash_table [index] ->next == NULL ) ```

Comment: Why are you not initializing `hash_table` ? It will certainly crash when you call `hash_table[index]->next` because you never initialize it

Comment: @LucasGras how can i  initialize it

Comment: What is the purpose of this array ? Since it’s not initialized with any values. How do you want to use it ?

Comment: i want to use it as a hash table with linked list , an array of linked list

Comment: So you should initialize your array with NULL pointers first

Answer (score 0):

At line 34:

```
if (item != NULL )
```

It is too late to check this; you already initialized item;  what you most likely meant was:

```
if (position != NULL) {
    /* leave code as is. */
} else {
    hash_table[index] = item;
}
```

as a readability note, this:

```
a[index]->thing
```

is almost universally preferred to variants such as:

```
a [index]->thing
a[index] ->thing
a[index] -> thing
a [index] -> thing
...
```

spaces around unary *,-,+,~,!,++,-- and binary [], (), -> are aesthetically unappealing to most readers.